# understanding classes and what is causing this attribute error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm very new to coding and have picked up learning how to use Python. I started learning about classes a few days ago and I'm sorta confused by them but I the more I practice with it, the more I'm starting to understand a little. So, for practice, I tried executing this code but keep getting an Attribute Error:

```
>>> class Hero:
     def __init__(self):
         self.health = 100
     def eat (self, food):
         if food == ham:
             print 'Bob has gained health!'
             self.health+=self.HealthBonus
         elif food == poison:
             print 'Oh no! Bob has taken damage!'
             self.health-=self.HealthDown

>>> class Ham:
     def __init__ (self):
         self.name = 'ham'
         self.HealthBonus = 10

>>> class Poison:
     def __init__ (self):
         self.name = 'poison'
         self.HealthDown = 20

>>> bob=Hero()
>>> ham=Ham()
>>> poison=Poison()
>>> bob.eat(ham)
Bob has gained health!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    bob.eat(ham)
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 7, in eat
    self.health+=self.HealthBonus
AttributeError: Hero instance has no attribute 'HealthBonus'
```

Can someone help me identify the cause of this Attribute Error?

Comment: You are trying to reference the hero object when you should be accessing the food object i.i. `food.HealthBonus`

Comment: As an aside, you should really be learning Python 3 instead of Python 2. Python 2 is approaching it's official end of life date, so, unless your employer is making you use it, I would switch to 3 if I were you

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies here:

```
>>> class Hero:
     def __init__(self):
         self.health = 100
     def eat (self, food):
         if food == ham:
             print 'Bob has gained health!'
             self.health+=self.HealthBonus
         elif food == poison:
             print 'Oh no! Bob has taken damage!'
             self.health-=self.HealthDown
```

You have "self.HealthBonus" and self refers to the instance of the class which owns the current method (function) being called. Eat is owned by the **Hero** class. When you pass your **food** variable to the eat method, the Food is what has the health bonus not the Hero. Change to this:

```
>>> class Hero:
     def __init__(self):
         self.health = 100
     def eat (self, food):
         if food == ham:
             print 'Bob has gained health!'
             self.health+=food.HealthBonus
         elif food == poison:
             print 'Oh no! Bob has taken damage!'
             self.health-=food.HealthDown
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga great note, I'll update the wording!